# Wordpress - How to show header on every page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I have a header image on the homepage. It's only showing up on the homepage but I need it to show on every page. I found this code in the header.php file which I believe needs to be changed, but I'm not very familiar with php.

This is the code for the header image in the header.php file:

```
<?php $disable_page_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'minimal_portfolio_page_title', true ); 
if( $disable_page_title !== 'on' ): ?>
    <?php if( !is_front_page()):  ?>
        <section class="page-header jumbotron <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>bg-image<?php endif; ?>"  <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?> style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url( get_header_image() ); ?>');" <?php endif; ?>>
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?><span class="bg-overlay"></span><?php endif; ?>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="title-wrap">
                                <?php if( is_page() || is_single() ){ ?>
                                        <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php } elseif( is_search() ){ ?>
                                    <?php /* translators: %s: search term */
                                        $page_title = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'minimal-portfolio' ),  get_search_query() ); 
                                    ?>
                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( $page_title ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php }elseif( is_404() ){ ?>

                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( 'Page Not Found: 404', 'minimal-portfolio' ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php }elseif( is_home() ){ ?>

                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h2>

                                    <?php } else{

                                        the_archive_title( '<h2 class="page-title">', '</h2>' );
                                    }

                                    if( $minimal_portfolio_breadcrumb_status ):
                                        minimal_portfolio_breadcrumbs();
                                    endif;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif;
    endif; ?>
```

Thank you!

Edit: This is how it shows on all pages but the home page. But I would like it to show the full header instead of only a section of it with the page title.

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Seu.png)

This is the home page, where it shows the full header and how I'd like it to show on every page instead of how it does in the image above.
[Home Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcdvn.png)

Comment: can you let me know which theme you are using.

Comment: I'm using the "Minimal Portfolio" theme.

Comment: did you tried adding the featured image to the pages

Comment: Yes I did. Also I should add that instead of displaying a full header, on every other page it only shows a small area of the header, with a black overlay and title over it. If that makes sense?

Comment: I uploaded some images to better explain what I mean in my original post.

Comment: is there any else part of this "if( !is_front_page()):" section also the code you posted is not complete there is endif portion missing of this if section can you paste complete code?

Comment: I am not sure where it ended exactly so I copied it all. It should be updated now.

Comment: @kyra can i see your webpage. will help you to solve the issue. my mail id is: `pullata.praveen@gmail.com`

Comment: Of course, emailed it to you.

Comment: @KyraLane If the below code works. please vote up or comment if it did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are not familiar with PHP so you can use this plugin for the header image.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/unique-headers/

I think its work for you

Comment: I tried this as well and it didn't override the current theme's headers and didn't add anything unfortunately. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below-attached code from `header.php`

```
<?php $disable_page_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'minimal_portfolio_page_title', true ); 
    if( $disable_page_title !== 'on' ): ?>
        <?php if( !is_front_page()):  ?>
            <section class="page-header jumbotron <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>bg-image<?php endif; ?>"  <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?> style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url( get_header_image() ); ?>');" <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?><span class="bg-overlay"></span><?php endif; ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="title-wrap">
                                <?php if( is_page() || is_single() ){ ?>
                                        <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php } elseif( is_search() ){ ?>
                                    <?php /* translators: %s: search term */
                                        $page_title = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'minimal-portfolio' ),  get_search_query() ); 
                                    ?>
                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( $page_title ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php }elseif( is_404() ){ ?>

                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( 'Page Not Found: 404', 'minimal-portfolio' ); ?></h2>

                                    <?php }elseif( is_home() ){ ?>

                                    <h2 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h2>

                                    <?php } else{

                                        the_archive_title( '<h2 class="page-title">', '</h2>' );
                                    }

                                    if( $minimal_portfolio_breadcrumb_status ):
                                        minimal_portfolio_breadcrumbs();
                                    endif;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <?php endif;
    endif; ?>
```

And add this code in your `page.php`

```
<?php if( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<div class="header-banner"> 
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo absint( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo absint( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: When removing the code in the header.php I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /home1/kyra/public_html/wp-content/themes/minimal-portfolio/page.php on line 47